# delete checked items from checkedListBox c#

Tags: c#, checklistbox

I want to remove several  checked items  from checkedListBox but I can't.This is my example. I was trying it but i was imposiible to get.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++){
            if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to reverse the loop. If you have a CheckedListBox of 2 items, both checked. If you delete `item 1` then `item 2` becomes` the new `item 1` and hence will never be deleted.

Comment: is it correct ?
for (int i = checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i > 0 ; i--)
            {
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i]);
                }
            }

Comment: Because `ì`in  `checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i]` and `checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i)` points to the wrong index after an item is deleted. If you reverse the loop that will not happen.

Comment: I have to inicialite to CheckedListBox.item.count?

Comment: use `LINQ` for delete items from Data SOURCE

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a CheckedListBox of 2 items, both checked. If you delete `item 1` then `item 2` becomes the new `item 1` and hence will never be deleted.

This is what's going on in detail:

1. `i` is initialized to 0.
2. `i` is less than `checkedListBox1.Items.Count` (which is 2). Loop entered.
3. `checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i)` returns true.
4. `checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i])` removes item at 
   index 0.
5. `i` is incremented to 1.
6. End of loop.
7. `i` is **not** less than `checkedListBox1.Items.Count` (which is 1) and the loop exits.

hence `item 2` will not be deleted.

Reverse the loop and it should work:

```
for (int i = checkedListBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
  {
    checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(checkedListBox1.Items[i]);
  }
}
```

Another way of doing this is as follows:

```
while (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
{
  checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(checkedListBox.CheckedIndices[0]);
}
```

And another:

```
while (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[0]);
}
```

Yet another:

```
foreach (var i in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Going on:

```
for(var i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
{
    ((IList) checkedListBox1.CheckedItems).Remove(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[0]);
}
```

Comment: This almost works, since the checkedListBox is using zero-based numbering, it should be `int i = checkedListBox1.Items.Count - 1;`

Comment: Don't work. {"Index outside the boundaries of the matrix."}

Comment: @Devator: Good catch. Fixed.

Comment: I copy it. I have 3 items. I check the second and third and I get this error: {"Index outside the boundaries of the matrix.}

Comment: @Airsa97: Yes. Noticed that I copied your code (with `checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i]). Should be `checkedListBox1.Items[i]`.

Comment: correct!!! It run!!! but I dont undenstand why I have to write checkListBox1.Items [i] and not use checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i]

Comment: @Airsa97: Because `i` is bound to `checkListBox1.Items` and not `checkListBox1.CheckedItems`. They have different amount of objects and the indices are different for the same objects. Lets say you have two items. Index 0 and 1. And the second one is checked. then `checkListBox1.CheckedItems[0]` is the same as `checkListBox1.Items[1]` and as you can see the indices don't match.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen second one dont work because I have 3 items. I check the second and third and it delete only second one

Comment: @Airsa97: Should work... Check that you are using `index of 0` (`CheckedItems[0]`) instead of `index of i` (`CheckedItems[i]`) and also that the condition is on `CheckedItems.Count` not `Items.Count`